# Small Icon on Notification not working correctly

Tags: android, notifications, android-drawable

I've been strugling with setting up proper small icon for notification. For some time I thought its only possible to create white icons to appear on the top bar but by mistake (typing wrong `id` of drawable) I've noticed that its possible to also add color image :
[image]

But after swipping the top bar down, the second place where icon is visible is all gray (big gray dot):
[image]

Is there a way to change that dark grey circle to the proper small_icon ?

My code :

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default");
 b.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pck_sign)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.pck_sign))
            .setTicker("{Time to watch some cool stuff!}")
            .setContentTitle("My Cool App")
            .setContentText("Time to watch some cool stuff!")
            .setContentInfo("INFO")
            .setContentIntent(pendingI);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's happened because the icon size is not the correct, check this documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar

Comment: To complement: if you want to generate a proper icon use this tool https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Comment: @Karzel A quote from the link: "Status bar icons... must be white on a transparent background."